# How can i load data on specific tab in android?

Tags: java, android

My task is to load data on 50th screen out of 100 screens in one tab activity and also to increment date on forward swipe and decrement date on backward swipe.

I wrote code to increment date and made 50th screen as my current screen but i don't know how to load that current date in 50th screen and to decrement date on backward swipe.

Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Tab2 self;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(50);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 100;
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            //TabHost tabHost = Tab2.self.getTabHost();
            //tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

            return Tab2.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
             return "SECTION 3";
        }
    }
}
```

and my tab activity is

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {
    private int position;

    public Tab2() {

    }

    public static Tab2 newInstance(int position) {
        Tab2 fragment = new Tab2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            position = getArguments().getInt("position");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, position);
        String dte = sdf.format(c.getTime()).toString();

        TextView textView2 =  getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView2.setText(dte);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
In your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date());
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, position);
    String dte = sdf.format(c.getTime()).toString();

    TextView textView2 =  getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2.setText(dte);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I think there is some mistake in parsing date.It shows me some error.

Comment: My bad didn't test the code myself. This should work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one tab to have specific data, you need to handle that case in the adapter

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f =  Tab2.newInstance(position);
        if (position == specificPosition) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
            // put into args... 
            f.setArguments(args);
        }
        return f;
    }
```

Regarding swipe direction, I think you need to attach the listener on the ViewPager.

Comment: By using newInstance? I wouldn't put an if statement in there